# overwrite the preventDefault() in another method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a this call

```
<a onclick="facebookLogin();" class="facebook_btn_homepage" href="/signup">
<img src="/images/facebook_btn2.png?1280194712" alt="Facebook_btn2"></a>

    $('.facebook_btn_homepage').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

but in the function facebookLogin() i want to overwrite the

```
 function facebookLogin() {
   FB.login(function(response) {
 //i want to overwrite the preventDefault and go to another 
     //page because its trying to go to another url and the preventDefault 
     //is stopping the page from going to another url
```

Comment: so why not just remove that event.preventDefault() line?

Comment: because i need it to not go to the other page right away...i need to go some action and then move to the other page and if i take it out it will go to the other url right away which i dont want

Answer (score 3):

You can call `preventDefault()`, then set the `window.location` manually when you need to.

```
$('.facebook_btn_homepage').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // do some stuff

    // then manually go to the next page
    window.location.href = this.href;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use both the `onclick` attribute and jQuery's click event handler?

If you remove the `onclick` call to `facebookLogin()` and put that in the jQuery click handler, you could decide in the facebookLogin() function whether or not you even need to prevent the default action (going to the URL specified in the `href`).

Or am I missing something?